# Why am i getting a null reference exception on a mocked test object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks, nullreferenceexception

I have the following

```
IdleClass idleSend = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IdleClass >();
SpeedClass speedSend = MockRepository.GenerateMock<SpeeClass >();
idleSend.Expect(x => x.IsUnitInSystem(networkID)).Return(true).Repeat.Any();
speedSend.Expect(x => x.IsUnitInSystem(networkID)).Return(true).Repeat.Any();
```

and The original IsUnitInSystem(networkID) function (in a subclass for IdleClass and SpeedClass) is below:

```
public bool IsUnitInSystem(string networkID)
        {
            DateTime outVal = default(DateTime);
            return m_list1.DoesListContainUnit(networkID) ||
                   m_list2.TryGetValue(networkID, out outVal) ||
                   m_list3.TryGetValue(networkID, out outVal) ||
                   m_list4.TryGetValue(networkID, out outVal) ||
                   m_list5.TryGetValue(networkID, out outVal);
        }
```

I am reviving a System.NullReferenceException on the return line in the IsUnitInSystem function.

Stack Trace:

```
IdleClass.IsUnitInSystem(String networkID)
PendingTest.<ResendClassTest>b__1b(IdleClass x)
RhinoMocksExtension.Expect[T,R](T mock, Function'2 action)
PendingTest.ResendClassTest()
```

What i don't understand is why and how the program is even getting into the function when i have specified a .Expect functionality for the function?

Comment: Just because the function comes within an `Expect` clause doesn't mean it won't run normally. When the code hits the expect line, it goes into the function, and if m_list1 is null you get your null reference.

Comment: make sure networkid matches on calls

Comment: then whats the point of having expect? i want to bypass the function being called because the lists will always be null in my tests.

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @GabeMoothart this is in a unit test, so it will be small, but yes i can post it

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: yea i know why its a null reference, try reading the question again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method you are trying to mock must be able to be implemented by the mock object, meaning it must be marked as virtual if you are mocking a concrete class.

Take a look at the following post for some more info: [Rhino Mocks stubs and mocks are only good for interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388033/rhino-mocks-stubs-and-mocks-are-only-good-for-interfaces)

Comment: Holy crap, that's exactly what it was ! they cant mock a non virtual function!  Thanks sir.