# Why is a method called from the Expect() statement?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I am trying to set an expectation on a Mocked object to find out if the method was called as expected.

I use the following code to achieve it.

```
//// Create a mocked object(arrange)
A controller = MockRepository.GenerateMock<A>();
someObject.Stub(x => x.Resolve(typeof(A))).Return(controller);

//// Act i.e. call the target function where the controller is created
this._target.InvokePrivateMethod("OnTargetUpdated", false, this, eventArgs);

//// Assert
controller.AssertWasCalled(x => x.UpdateTarget(targetInfo2), o => o.Repeat.Once());
```

However, when i try to assert if the "UpdateTarget()" was called the flow goes into the code of the method. I simply want to check "If the method was called" and not "call the method".

Comment: I came across another case where in i wanted to mock a property of an object. This property actually returns a custom type. I wanted to return an instance of the object which i already had. When i tried stubbing/mocking the property it created a proxy implementation of the custom class instead of returning the object i wanted it to return.

Comment: It's difficult to figure out what exactly happens here. A few questions to clarify: What is `A`? Is it an interface? Or it is a class? If `A` is a class then is `UpdateTarget()` _virtual_ method? Can you provide the complete example which reproduces your issue?

Comment: @Alexander Stepaniuk 'A' is a class and the method is not virtual. There's some code inside this method which contains some objects which are not mocked and hence when this method is executed i get exceptions. So, i just want to check if this method was invoked. To reproduce this, you could simply throw an exception from the method "UpdateTarget".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As method `UpdateTarget()` is non-virtual then Rhino Mock can't intercept call to it.

That's why the real method is executed instead.
See details e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388033/rhino-mocks-stubs-and-mocks-are-only-good-for-interfaces).

To get your test working you need to make mocked method virtual. Or even better if you use interface here instead of class.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. Thanks anyways.